# Desktop software for cloud backup in buckets?

Tags: backup, cloud

I already do backup on external HDD and I'm planing to do cloud backup as well.

As I could see, for long-term storage, not readily available (i.e., you have to wait hours to begin the recovery), some storage services are cheaper (AWS, BackBlaze, and so on).

But the storage is done in buckets, and also data transfer (upload and download) is billed.

So I need some backup tool that:

- can store files on the cloud
- Does incremental backups (to minimize costs of data transfer)
- keeps control of files stored in buckets for long term storage
- perhaps can deal with the local, external HDD backup.

Bonus for GPL or not proprietary data formats, as I need to be sure that I'll be able to recover the files if necessary without depending on a proprietary software/format to untar/decrypt/unzip my files.

Answer (score 1):

For backing up data from servers, I'm using [AzCopy v10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) to synchronize local files to Azure Blob Storage.

- Local copy can be considered always authoritative.
- Only new/changed files are
  copied.
- Locally deleted files can be deleted from remote.
- Azure Blob Storage has settings to automatically retain deleted blobs for some time period.
- Azure offers additional apps that can do many things, such as auto-delete blobs on a timer.

AzCopy is a simple command-line tool similar to robocopy, rsync, etc. You specify source, destination, and options.

As far as recovery times, you have options of immediate availability or archive storage (hours). You also have geo-redundancy options.

For managing your files, such as when you need to recover something, a GUI is available: [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).